# Accelerating a spaceship to near speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, space-travel

Hypothetically, suppose we have the ability to accelerate a spaceship to near speed of light (lets say 0.9c). From what I remember of relativistic kinematics, the energy required to accelerate the ship to that speed be given by:

$$ KE = mc^2 (\gamma -1) $$

If so, let us suppose the spaceship is to travel to the nearest neighbouring star. What would be the energy for the spaceship to maintain that velocity of 0.9c.

Comment: The problem is not coasting but decelerating at the destination.

Comment: I see! Hypothetically speaking, what forces could cause a deceleration of such spaceship? Would the gravitational potential of a nearby blackhole cause such disturbance?

Answer (score 3):

Maintaining a constant velocity requires no energy.

Comment: But don't forget that it takes energy to slow down at the destination. And then there's the return...

Comment: @hdhondt The OP did not ask about that.